# WooCommerce UWP(C#)

Tags: c#, wordpress, visual-studio, woocommerce, uwp

I writing app  for UWP(C#)

I need to connect to woo commerce on web site.

I write some code and has errors.

In Main .cs file I write this code

```
 string ConsumerKey = "ck_f03bbd67e26a96604ddb188dbd63be3d252891ab";
        string ConsumerSecret = "cs_f8583f42dd1d75da832574b7ad6e649a0687f88f";
        string StoreUrl = "https://www.simplegames.com.ua";
        bool Isssl = true;
        WoocommerceApiClient client2 = new WoocommerceApiClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, StoreUrl, Isssl);
        string orders = client2.GetProducts();
```

with this code is all okay.

Also I have class with connecting

Code of class.

```
 private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
    {
        var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
        return hash.ComputeHash(message);
    }

    private string Hash(string input)
    {
        using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
                sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public const string API_ENDPOINT = "wc-api/v1/";
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerSecret { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsSsl { get; set; }

    public WoocommerceApiClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string storeUrl, bool isSsl = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerSecret) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("ConsumerKey, consumerSecret and storeUrl are required");
        }
        this.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
        this.ApiUrl = storeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + API_ENDPOINT;
        this.IsSsl = isSsl;
    }

    public string GetAllProducts()
    {
        return MakeApiCall("products", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "filter[limit]", "2000" } });
    }
    public string GetProducts()
    {
        return MakeApiCall("products");
    }

    private string MakeApiCall(string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null, string method = "GET")
    {
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        parameters["oauth_consumer_key"] = this.ConsumerKey;
        parameters["oauth_timestamp"] =
            DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds.ToString();
        parameters["oauth_timestamp"] = parameters["oauth_timestamp"].Substring(0,
            parameters["oauth_timestamp"].IndexOf("."));
        parameters["oauth_nonce"] = Hash(parameters["oauth_timestamp"]);
        parameters["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA256";
        parameters["oauth_signature"] = GenerateSignature(parameters, method, endpoint);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var pair in parameters)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value));
        }
        var url = this.ApiUrl + endpoint + "?" + sb.ToString().Substring(1).Replace("%5b", "%5B").Replace("%5d", "%5D");
        var result = wc.DownloadString(url);
        return result;
    }

    private string GenerateSignature(Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string method, string endpoint)
    {
        var baserequesturi = Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.ApiUrl + endpoint), "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper());
        var normalized = NormalizeParameters(parameters);

        var signingstring = string.Format("{0}&{1}&{2}", method, baserequesturi,
            string.Join("%26", normalized.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.Key + "%3D" + x.Value)));
        var signature =
            Convert.ToBase64String(HashHMAC(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.ConsumerSecret),
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingstring)));
        Debug.WriteLine(signature);
        return signature;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> NormalizeParameters(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var pair in parameters)
        {
            var key = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(pair.Key));
            key = Regex.Replace(key, "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper()).Replace("%", "%25");
            var value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(pair.Value));
            value = Regex.Replace(value, "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper()).Replace("%", "%25");
            result.Add(key, value);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have this errors.

```
1)


  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context    Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 85  Active
```

2)  `Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll' and no extension method 'ConvertAll' accepting a first argument of type 'List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 98  Active`

```
3) Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HMACSHA256' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 18  Active

4) Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SHA1Managed' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 24  Active

5)Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 81  Active

6)Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'  Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 29  Active
```

Help me fix this errors please.

Thank's for your help.

**UPDATE**

I think I found fix for this error

```
1)


  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context    Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 85  Active
```

It is `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode`

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The .Net cryptography API is no longer available. It has been replaced by the WinRT api available from [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx)

To generate the hash code you need, you will have to use [CryptographicHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographichash.aspx) class

```
// Create a string that contains the name of the hashing algorithm to use.
String strAlgName = HashAlgorithmNames.Sha512;

// Create a HashAlgorithmProvider object.
HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);

// Create a CryptographicHash object. This object can be reused to continually
// hash new messages.
CryptographicHash objHash = objAlgProv.CreateHash();

// Hash message 1.
String strMsg1 = "This is message 1.";
IBuffer buffMsg1 = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg1, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
objHash.Append(buffMsg1);
IBuffer buffHash1 = objHash.GetValueAndReset();
```

Using the [CryptographicBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.aspx), you can then easily transform the hash's buffer to a base64 or hex string.